# Launch terminal application and send command using python

Tags: python, macos, terminal, scripting

How can I launch a 3rd party terminal application and send a command to it using python? I have been doing this for a while using `appscript.app('Terminal').do_script('script').run()`, but I now need to be able to launch the terminal called Hyper and send a command. My code does not work with Hyper for some reason...any ideas?

Comment: I am also open for suggestions for other 3rd party terminals that will work easier...

Comment: Have you tried this `os.system(command)`?

Comment: I try to avoid os.system, since it surpasses the output from my scripts. Ive also looked into subprocess...but how can I launch an app and then call commands with subprocess?

Comment: Try this `os.popen(command).read()`

Comment: what would the command be to launch Hyper.app?

Comment: that allows me to open it with open /path/to/hyper.app...but how can I pass a command

Comment: It may or may not be applicable to your probelm, but maybe `pexpect` would be useful for you?